# jQuery No longer accepting attr("Checked") === true Logic

Tags: jquery, attr

I've noticed that after a upgrade to the latest version of jquery (1.7.1) that the following code no longer evalulates

```
if( $('#item').attr('checked') === true ){
    //do something
}
```

I sort of understand why they may have made this change but does anyone have a link to documentation of why they have done this? I want to ensure my code works correctly.. and it seems that maybe I have been incorrectly using the above for quite a while.

Comment: `.attr('checked')` after 1.6 properly returns a string (all attributes are strings). If you want a boolean property, use the new `.prop()` method.

Comment: This comment is as close to the answer as anyone has got! and I didnt' know about the prop method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not working because every browser have their own way to make it checked for example:

checked, checked="checked", checked="true".

so you should use selector :checked intead of attribute. and jQuery will take care about all browsers :)

Comment: Even if different browsers use different values in the attribute, the attribute is still a `string` and not a `boolean`. jQuery was converting it to `boolean` prior to 1.6.0.

Comment: Marked as answer for actually helping clear up the question, instead of assuming I didn't know how to actually check my object. which most of these answers are!

Answer (score 4):

rather use

```
if( $('#item').is(':checked')){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This doesnt answer my question. I knew how to fix the bug. I wanted to know the reason for jQuery change of mind!

Comment: To push **dummy** developers, who need 'professionals' to teach them jQuery, and don't RTFM theirselves ask for courses from jQuery founders (like they did at first)!!!

Answer (score 4):

Use `.is` to check if a checkbox is checked. See below,

```
if( $('#item').is(':checked')){
..
```

**Edit:**

<s>As far as I know, jQuery's `$('#item').attr('checked')` never returned true. It returns `checked` or `undefined`.</s>

As Kevin pointed out,

> .attr('checked') after 1.6 properly returns a string (all attributes
>   are strings). If you want a boolean property, use the new .prop()
>   method

If you want to compare `true`, then use `this.checked`. See below, <-- I prefer using `this.checked` as this is faster than any other method.

```
if (this.checked === true) {
..
```

or

Use `.prop` like below, [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Z2rGe/1/)

```
if($(this).prop('checked') === true) {
..
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/Z2rGe/)

Comment: 1.5.2: http://jsfiddle.net/ja2yH/  1.6.4: http://jsfiddle.net/ja2yH/1/  Prior to the addition of the `.prop` method, `.attr` (improperly in my opinion) returned values other than strings for some attributes.

Comment: @KevinB I never knew.. I learned one more new stuff today. :) Thx.